# A relaxation-free variant of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, shortest-path, dijkstras-algorithm

I have come up with a relaxation-free variant of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm, and I would like to see if it's correct. Here is the pseudocode for finding the shortest distance from a node $\alpha$ to another node $\beta$.

1. Initialize an empty priority queue $Q$ and an empty hash map $H$.
2. Add $\alpha$ to $Q$ with a "distance" of $0$.
3. While $Q$ is not empty,

   1. Pop the node with the shortest distance. Denote the node with $n$ and its distance with $d$.
   2. If $n = \beta$, then return $d$.
   3. If $n$ is present in $H$, then continue to the next iteration.
   4. Add $n$ to $H$ with a distance value of $d$.
   5. For each neighbor $m$ of $n$, denote the distance from $n$ to $m$ with $w$

      1. Add $m$ to $Q$ with a distance value of $d + w$.
4. If we reach here, then it's impossible to reach $b$ from $a$.

(Note that you can replace the hash map $H$ with a hash set because only the presence of keys matters. I used a hash map solely to make the analysis easier.)

---

**Analysis:** First we show that when we pop a "distance" of $d$ from $Q$, all valid "routes" starting from $\alpha$ with a "distance" smaller than $d$ have already been "explored". Suppose there exists an unexplored shorter route. Denote the last explored node on that route with $u$ (there exists at least one explored node on that route, i.e. $\alpha$), and the first unexplored node on that route with $v$ (such a node exists since the route is unexplored). Since $u$ has been explored, $Q$ contains all of its immediate neighbours, including $v$. The distance between $a$ and $v$ is smaller than the total distance of that route, which is smaller than $d$ by construction. Given that $v$ is in $Q$ with a smaller distance than $d$, the priority queue should popped it before popping $n$, but $u$ is still unexplored when processing $n$, which creates a contradiction.

If a newly popped node $n$ is not in $H$, then $n$ has not been reached until now, which means it is impossible to reach $n$ with a distance shorter than $d$. Thus, $d$ is the shortest possible distance from $a$ to $n$, so the algorithm always gives the correct result.

**Question:** Am I right? How do I express the proof of correctness more formally? The analysis above doesn't seem formal enough since I did not rigorously define concepts like "distance", "route", "explore", "first", and "last". This is probably in turn because the pseudocode is not clear enough to enable rigorous reasoning, so I am happy to provide clarification.

As a bonus, does my variant run faster or take less space than [the vanilla algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode)?

---

(I am aware that we have a [similar question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88791/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-without-relaxation) on this site, but my algorithm is different from Leo's. Moreover, Leo edited their question after an answer has been posted, rendering it stale.)

Comment: At step 5.1, $m$ might already be in $Q$. What then is an upper limit for $|Q|$? The question is important because it affects both space and time requirements (bigger priority queues are slower). Relaxation avoids adding duplicate nodes to the queue. That said, I think your algo gives the right answer. By the way, ots usual to number nodes sequentially, which means that you can replace $H$ with a simple vector. Might not be asymptotically faster but it is faster (and uses less memory).

Comment: @rici Could you elaborate on how relaxation helps limiting the size of $Q$? I think relaxation merely maintains $H$, but the distance values in $H$ is never read from (the algorithm only checks if a given node is present in $H$), and each and all neighbors of a unvisited node are still pushed into $Q$.

Comment: If you look at the algorithm in the Wikipedia page you link to, the priority queue is initialised with all the nodes, each with an infinite length, and the relaxation step is conditional upon the newly-discovered path length being less than the recorded path length. In that case, the relaxation step calls `Q.decrease_priority(v, alt)`, which does not push anything onto $Q$. You might reasonably say that the $Q$-manipulation is not really part of the relaxation but rather another computation with the same guard, but the effect is the same.

Comment: Your algorithm is basically the second alternative in the WP article (the one with footnote number 17). The "no decrement" algorithm in the paper indicated in footnote 17 is not unconditional, however; it only pushes the new value if the path was relaxed. That still can blow up the queue, but less than an unconditional push would, I think.

Comment: If you don't consider decrease_priority to be part of relaxation, then relaxation is trivial, just a couple of assignments. The part of relaxation that complicates the implementation is precisely the decrease_priority procedure, because that function needs to be able to rapidly find the node whose priority is to be reduced.

Comment: @rici I see. It looks like relaxation ensures that $Q$ doesn't contain duplicate nodes, which limits the size of $Q$ to $V$, the number of nodes in the graph. Without relaxation, $Q$ could contain as many elements as $E$, the number of edges in the graph. How does relaxation affect time complexity though? On the one hand, a smaller $Q$ is a faster $Q$; on the other hand, relaxation takes time (assuming you maintain the index of each node in the binary heap with a hash map, calling `decrease_priority` takes $O(ln(V))$ for each edge, and $O(E \cdot ln(V))$ in total?).

Comment: It's no faster to add an element to a priority queue than to adjust the priority of an existing element. At least in an ordinary binary heap, both of those operations do exactly the same thing, because pushing a new value consists of putting it at the end of the heap and then adjusting its position according to its priority. That doesn't really answer your question, though. As Cormen points out, if we don't use a priority queue and find the minimum length element using linear search, then decrease_priority is $O(1)$ and find_minimum is $O(V)$; the total cost is $O(V^2+E)$.

Comment: WIth a PQ, decrease_priority is $O(\log V)$ and find_minimum is $O(\log V)$, so the total cost is $O((V + E)\log V)$. Which of those is less will depend on the sparseness of the graph. The paper referenced at footnote 17 in the WP article reports some empirical tests, so you might want to take a look at it.

Comment: @rici That makes sense, but what about the theoretical time complexity of using a PQ but does *not* do relaxation, i.e. keep pushing nodes to $Q$ even if there might be duplicates (which is exactly what my algorithm is doing)? As $Q$ grows large, it could take more time to do `insert` and `pop_min` ($O(ln(V))$ with relaxation, and $O(ln(E))$ without relaxation?).

Comment: Indeed. I suppose that in the worst case, with a pathological graph, it could reach $O((E + V) \log E)$. However, $E = O(V^2)$, so $\log E = 2 \log V$ and $O(\log E) = O(\log V)$. In this case, as in many, the asymptotes aren't telling the whole story :-) Thus, the empirical results are probably useful. Although they may not apply to modern hardware.

Comment: @rici More accurately, it's $E \in O(V^2)$ and $O(\log E) \subset O(\log V)$ :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128195/discussion-between-nalzok-and-rici).

Comment: Sorry. It's sleeptime here.

Comment: @rici That's okay. Good night!

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm guarantees that the first time a node is expanded, an optimal path to it has been already found. It seems to me that H here just resembles a closed list (a complicated one indeed because distances are not necessary), so that it merely avoids duplicate expansion.

Comment: @CarlosLinaresLópez Not sure what you mean by "closed list", but $H$ basically functions as a hash set that checks if a given node has already been visited.